# Converting PHP array to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm having trouble here! There seems to be something wrong due to my lack of knowledge in JSON and JS. Here's my little code:

```
$markersData = array();

$x = 0;
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $type = $row['type'];
  $markersData[$type][$x]['name'] = $row['name'];
  $markersData[$type][$x]['location_latitude'] = $row['location_latitude'];
  $markersData[$type][$x]['location_longitude'] = $row['location_longitude'];
  $markersData[$type][$x]['map_image_url'] = '';
  $markersData[$type][$x]['name_point'] = $row['name_point'];
  $markersData[$type][$x]['description_point'] = $row['description_point'];
  $markersData[$type][$x]['url_point'] = $global['rootURI'] . '/view.php?id=' . $row['id'];
  $x ++;
}
```

and I am storing the SQL data on a php array directly after retrieving the row. Now, using JSON approach, here was my trial but apparently it isn't loading or working.

```
var
    mapObject,
    markers = [],
    markersData = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($markersData); ?>' );
```

And I'm looking for the converted php array to do the same job as this JS code:

```
 var
    mapObject,
    markers = [],
    markersData = {
            'Shop': [
            {
                name: 'Bondi Beach',
                location_latitude: 43.119445, 
                location_longitude: 131.881006,
                map_image_url: 'img/img.png',
                name_point: 'Vladivostok',
                description_point: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard',
                url_point: '02.html'
            }
            ],
            'Cinema': [
            {
                name: 'Bondi Beach',
                location_latitude: 43.124034, 
                location_longitude: 131.883517,
                map_image_url: 'img/img.png',
                name_point: 'Vladivostok',
                description_point: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard',
                url_point: '02.html'
            },
            {
                name: 'Coogee Beach',
                location_latitude: 43.126117, 
                location_longitude: 131.877423,
                map_image_url: 'img/img2.png',
                name_point: 'Matart Group',
                description_point: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard',
                url_point: '02.html'
            }
            ]
        };
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: A few folks asked me to show them the output. It's available here: http://pastebin.com/7Ebz2GzP

Comment: try direct `markersData = <?php echo json_encode($markersData); ?>;`

Comment: please show the output of `echo json_encode($markersData);`

Comment: print the result of encoded json string and validate uisng `http://jsonlint.com/`

Comment: @Jigar Your solution does not seem to be working :(

Comment: @Steve Done. Check it out.

Comment: Then the very 1st comment by @Jigar is correct - did you try it? If so, whats not working?

Comment: @Steve Just realized. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_encode` to send the data to javascript like

```
echo json_encode($markersData);
```

and then in javascript you can use JSON.parse to make it a javascript object

```
response = JSON.parse(markersData, function(k,v){
                    return v;
                });
    console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) :

```
echo json_encode($markersData);
```

In JS parse it:

```
res = JSON.parse(markersData, function(a,b){ return b;});
   alert(res);
```